# How to count number of people, whose age equals certain number?

Tags: php, mysql

How to count number of people, whose age equals, for example, 18 years old?

```
<?php $emp_query=mysql_query("SELECT
  'employeeID',
  `LastName`,
  `birthday`,
  (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(`birthday`))-(RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)<RIGHT(`birthday`,5)
  ) AS `age`
FROM `employee`
ORDER BY `LastName`");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['employeeID']; ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['birthday']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo $row['age']?></td>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: YOu need to read up on mysql aggregate functions.  Also, don't use mysql_* for new code, it's deprecated, doesn't support Mysql 5 properly, is insecure, and will be removed from PHP in the future.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Can you outline what the specific problem is with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are satisfied with your `age` calculation, then you can rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(`birthday`))-(RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)<RIGHT(`birthday`,5)
             ) AS `age`
      FROM `employee`
     ) e
WHERE age = 18;
```

Comment: I thought that you couldn't use aliases in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @martincarlin87 . . . It is using a subquery.  You cannot use aliases in a `where` clause when they are defined in the `select` at the same level.

Comment: ah, just noticed the subquery, my bad.

Comment: Thanks. It is work! If I want to count all range of age (from 18 to 100)? How write this in array, in order to in the end I received all variables appropriate certain number of age. For example: $n18 - 5 (people), $n19 - 3........$n100 - 10 e.t.c. Help me!

Comment: You would use `group by age` instead of `where` (no filtering).  And probably add `age` to the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)-function to subtract a date with other date to get the difference of date in days.

```
SELECT 
    `employeeID`,
    `LastName`,
    `birthday`
FROM
    `employee`
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(`birthday`, CURDATE()) / 365 < specified_age
```

It's best to define a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) for it, which allows a dynamic input (the `specified_age`) and returns the rows which meets the condition. If you have one single input, simply replace the `specified_age` to a number, in years. Fe below 18 years, take `18` instead.

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: There should be a MySQL function to subtract one date from another and express the result in years.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$emp_query = mysql_query("SELECT 
`employeeID`, 
`LastName`, 
`birthday`, 
`year`, 
`age` 
WHERE `age` = $number 
FROM `employee` 
ORDER BY `LastName`");
```

Then "number" you can get from a form eg $number = $_POST['your form'];

if that's your setup, else you can just swap out $number in the query for a specific number and upload the file.

//do your while or foreach loop

Comment: The OP's database doesn't have an `age`-column, but one with `birthday`. Please also note that your answer allows SQLi and contains deprecated functions ( the `mysql_query()` ).

Comment: @KarelG True, didn't think of that tbh. OP should make it easier for himself, adding the column and start using PDO or sqli.  For OP: Scratch my answer.